# Почему не работает регулярное выражение по получению номера телефона?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть страница сайта. На странице есть следующий элемент:

```
<span class="phonebox"> телефон:<h4>+7 (999) 999-99-99</h4> </span>
```

Нужно получить телефон. 
Выполняю следующий код:

```
preg_match_all('#<h4>(([+]?[0-9\s-\(\)]{3,25})*$)#x', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);  
print_r($matches);
```

В ответ получаю пустой массив. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее будет так
`#<h4>(([+]?[0-9\s-\(\)]{3,25})*)#x`
с конца удалите `$` у вас ведь строка на этом не заканчивается